# How to use textual entailment model generated by fine-tuning STS models on HuggingFace

Tags: python, huggingface

I am trying to fine-tune an STS model for Textual Entailment classification for "entailment", "neutral", and "contradiction".

Here is the source code available on HuggingFace Sentence-BERT NLI: https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/blob/master/examples/training/nli/training_nli_v2.py

Part of the NLI training data: https://huggingface.co/datasets/snli

The script aims to create an NLI model based on the Semantic Textual Similarity benchmark with the code below:

```
# Save the path of the model
model_save_path = 'output/training_nli_v2_'+model_name.replace("/", "-")+'-'+datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
```

My question is how I can use the output model to predict 0(neutral), 1(entailment), or 2(contradiction).

Would it be like this? ref. https://huggingface.co/facebook/bart-large-mnli

```
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer

nli_model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('training_nli_v2_{model_name}')
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('training_nli_v2_{model_name}')

premise = "I am thirsty"
hypothesis = "I want water"

x = tokenizer.encode(premise, hypothesis, return_tensors='pt',
                     truncation_strategy='only_first')

logits = nli_model(x.to(device))[0]

# We throw away "neutral" (dim 1) and take the probability of
# "entailment" (2) as the probability of the label being true 

entail_contradiction_logits = logits[:,[0,2]]
probs = entail_contradiction_logits.softmax(dim=1)
prob_label_is_true = probs[:,1]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.